# Getting started with Xamarin.Android and Window Azue Storage

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I want to create a mobile app using Xamarin.Android that will allow users to add their names and email addresses to a list of athletes willing to meet-up for a game of golf, tennis, etc. The app will contain a page for users to enter their name and email address and another page for displaying the list of users. I want to store the users' names and email addresses in a table using Windows Azure but I can't find a package that works with Mono.Android.

Can anyone suggest the best approach for me? A guide or example would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Azure Mobile Apps - tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started/

Comment: Yes but I want everyone who downloads and uses the app to access the same table. Will I be able to accomplish that if I follow that guide? When I tried before it didn't seem like I would...

Comment: Yes - by default, everyone accesses the same table.  You have to do extra work for anything else.